# Pictures in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

I am working on a project in JavaScript. And I was wondering if there is a way to display an image, without using HTML. I am new to JavaScript. I do not mind links to pages I need to read. I just cannot find a place, which answers this question.

I simple wish to display it in a web browser, so all I need is a line of code which would replace this code in html:

```
<img src="my/string.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:1210px;height:688px">
```

Comment: What engine are you using to run your JavaScript? Given the question it is, presumably, not a web browser (or at least not from an HTML document loaded into a web browser), but that leaves a lot of options which will impact the possible answers.

Comment: Display an image, without HTML? Where would it appear, exactly?

Comment: You can do it without **HTML**, in a browser. You use the DOM. But I suspect that's not what you mean...

Comment: You could also do it with SVG or possibly even with XUL in an extension to modify the browser chrome and do it there. But again - probably not what you mean.

Comment: Are you asking how to manipulate the DOM with JS? There's a basic tutorial [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML). It's something you should learn the basics of before coming to Stackoverflow though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I simple wish to display it in a web browser, so all I need is a line of code which would replace this code in html:
>
> ```
> <img src="my/string.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:1210px;height:688px">
> ```

You can do that [with the DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR): You'd use `createElement` and `appendChild` or `insertBefore`:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "my/string.jpg";
img.alt = "Mountain View";
img.style.width = "1210px";
img.style.height = "688px";
document.body.appendChild(img); // Or wherever you want to put it
```

If you don't mind using HTML but just want to do it under programmatic control, you can use the `insertAdjacentHTML` method or the `innerHTML` property:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend',
    '<img src="my/string.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:1210px;height:688px">'
);
```

...or

```
someElement.innerHTML = '<img src="my/string.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:1210px;height:688px">';
```

Comment: I think i will add it using DOM thanks for the help.